# Close SimpleModal after using back button with History

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal, history.js

I'm using [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) and [Eric Martin's SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/). I have the following code:

```
jQuery(function() {

   var History = window.History;

   History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){
    var State = History.getState();
    History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
   });

   ('body').delegate('a', 'click', function () {
        $.modal("<div><h1>Test</h1></div>", {
            close: true,
            opacity: 70,
            onShow: function (){
                History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1");
            },
            onClose: function (){
                History.back();
                $.modal.close();
            }
        });
   });
});
```

Right now if you click on the link and the modal appears, it changes the state like it should. If you close the modal, it works fine, too.

The only thing that doesn't work is if you open the modal, and then use the browser's back button, it changes the state, but the modal doesn't close. How can I get the SimpleModal to close if it is open and the back button is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
    $.modal.close();
});
```

Or with the "window.onstatechange" History.js event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I put it in the `window.onstatechange` event, it breaks the modal and gives me the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'focus' of undefined`.

Comment: Then try: $(window).on('unload', function(){ $.modal.close(); });

Comment: It doesn't give the error, but same problem as before?